# Bit toggling confusion in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Hi I have written a program to toggle bits in char array. I found that when I am toggling the 7th bit I am getting wrong answer. Please help me.

```
int main() {
    int n,c;
    char dummy;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    char a[13];
    memset(a,0x00,13);
    for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
       scanf("%d",&c);
        dummy = c%8;
        a[c/8] ^= (1<<dummy);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int _i=0;_i<13;_i++)printf("%x ",a[_i]);
//    int result = lonelyinteger(n, a);
//    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}

Input:
9
4 9 95 93 57 4 57 93 9

Output:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **ffffff80** 0
```

I need the output as 80 only not ffffff80. Please help me with this.

Comment: `printf("%x ", a[_i]);` --> `printf("%x ", (unsigned char)a[_i]);`

Comment: it is sign extending the byte to a 32 bit number so (unsigned int)(a[-i]) may/should fix that.  Or dummy=a[_i];  then printf the dummy variable

Comment: @old_timer Casting to `unsigned int` does not work as expected.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for the help. unsigend char is working. I have declared the array as unsigned char a[13].

Comment: 50/50 chance without trying it...

Comment: Or use `"%hhx"`.

Comment: change `char a[13];` to `unsigned char a[13];`

Answer (score -1):

Remember that it is not only the signed-ness of the array type, but the signed-ness of the *integer literal* that you are shifting that matters. Make sure both are unsigned.

```
x ^= 1U << n;
```

Comment: This is good general advice; however `dummy` never exceeds `7` in OP's code, and there is no difference between  `x ^= (1 << 7)` and `x ^= (1u << 7)`.  The problem is more to do with the declared type of `x`